# Ajax.Actionlink in View in Areas folder not hitting the Controller's ActionResult

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a difficult time wiring up the Ajax.Actionlink to it's correct controller ActionResult.

I have a View page inside the Areas folder of my project (the path is **Areas/Feed/Views/Feed/Feed.cshtml**)
And the controller is in that same folder (path is (**Areas/Feed/Controllers/FeedController.cs**)

in the Feed.cshtml i have a simple Ajax.Actionresult like so:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Most Popular", "SortMostPopular", "Feed", new { Area = "Feed", UserLoginId = Model.FeedModel.UserLoginId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "fd-div-feed" }, new { @role = "menuitem", @tabindex = "-1" })
```

And the ActionResult method:

```
public ActionResult SortMostPopular(long UserLoginId)
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

The ajax.Actionlink is supposed to send over a *UserLoginId* of type long to the method and spit back a Partialview. For testing purposes it doesnt do anything yet and I put a breakpoint just before the **return PartialView()** to see if it would hit there - but it doesnt :'(

Instead, when I click the link it refreshes the TargetId (a div in this case) *fd-div-feed* with the entire view itself. This is driving me crazy lol. Anyone know why this is happening? I dont want to refresh the entire page, just the Target Element.

Also....I checked the source code and i am correctly referencing unobtrusive, jquery and all that.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here are my javascript files in this order:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap_offcanvas")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Helpers/ScrollbarHelper.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.json2.js")
```

Comment: Check the browser's dev console to monitor the details for network requests. The default HttpMethod for the ActionLink is GET so you might be seeing an old cached result (therefore you won't hit the breakpoint).

Comment: I checked in the console. Looks like there might be something wrong with the **jquery.unbtrusive** file? I get an error: _'Empty string passed to getElementById().'_ on line _fn = fn[parts.shift()];_ where fn is **undefined**??

Comment: You possibly included the javascript libraries in the wrong order. Be sure jquery is before jquery.unobtrusive. Please post your javascript includes so we can be sure everything is in order there.

Comment: The order looks correct assuming _jqueryval_ contains _jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js_.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. I've tried your code and it works. Try eliminating everything until you only have the bare minimum for your action link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why the trigger was not happening. My route config was incorrect and needed to change it around a bit. 
I initially had something like:

```
Feed/{Username}
```

But this needed to be changed to:

```
Feed/{Username}/{action}/{id}
```

to accommodate other method calls. So when in doubt check your route config!

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following to things:

1) Make sure that you definitely have the reference to the unobtrusive ajax library.

I know it seems trivial but from questions I have read it nearly always turns out to be that.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2) Make sure that your bundled scripts are ordered correctly.

If you are using wild-cards it orders them alphabetically which is often not what you want. 
I can't tell this from your question as the `RegisterBundles` is where the actual script files are loaded.